# How to access Build Settings in Xcode 6?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

There seems to be a lot of variations of how to access the Build Settings variables (i.e. to define the base URL of a web service for different `Debug` vs. `Release` environments).

I created a User-Defined variable in Project -> Building Settings, one for each environment. Let's call it `WEB_SERVICE_BASE_URL`.

How do I access it in the code? I'm using XCode 6 and Swift.

I've tried this but it doesn't work

```
let api_key = ${WEB_SERVICE_BASE_URL}
```

I've also tried this and it also doesn't work

```
let api_key = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("WEB_SERVICE_BASE_URL")
```

Any suggestions? This seems to be a often needed solution, it's so easy in Rails, but not so in iOS development.

Comment: The Swift compiler does not include a preprocessor. Instead, it takes advantage of compile-time attributes, build configurations, and language features to accomplish the same functionality. For this reason, preprocessor directives are not imported in Swift.

Comment: Still preprocessors are supported in ObjC, why not expose them in ObjC class and make call in Swift.

Comment: Swift has "lite" support of accessing build settings, refer to [Interact with C APIs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html).

Comment: Follow [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-quick-tip-managing-configurations-with-ease--mobile-18324) tutorial, though it uses objective c, it's pretty easy converting to swift.

Answer (score 42):

Here's how to set it up:

1. Add a User-Defined setting to your target's `Build Settings` (which you did with `WEB_SERVICE_BASE_URL`)
2. Add a new row to your target's `Info.plist` file with key: `WEB_SERVICE_BASE_URL`, type: `String`, value: `${WEB_SERVICE_BASE_URL}`

Here's how get the value:

```
let api_key = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "WEB_SERVICE_BASE_URL") as? String
```

*Note: These keys/values can be extracted from the package, so be sure to avoid storing sensitive data in there.*

Comment: Why do you need to add the entry to Info.plist?

Comment: Because the info.plist's `objectForInfoDictionaryKey()` method is how you grab the value that is determined at compile time (via build settings). If you don't add that entry to the .plist file, `objectForInfoDictionaryKey()` will return nil at runtime. There might be other ways to do this, but this way works just fine.

Comment: Great. Please take a look at my question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33220964/cant-access-build-setting

Comment: It was what I was looking for!

Comment: Here's a step by step guide (with images) for how to set this up in Xcode https://stackoverflow.com/a/74254208/4975772