# Xcode project environment variables

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6, xcode6.3

How to distinguish multiple environments in iOS app?

My Swift app uses external API connection and we have two API URLs - testing and productive.

Is there any way how to use one variable and set its value for testing in Xcode and another value for the AppStore release?

Currently I am using Xcode 6.3.1 
Application deployment target is iOS 8.1

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24645090/how-to-access-build-settings-in-xcode-6 for a possible solution using user-defined settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In swift we need to use "Swift Compiler - Custom Flags" instead of Pre Processor macro...

Set flag as shown in figure below [image]

Use below code for checking..

```
    var url;

    #if DebugURL
        url = ** Your Debug URL **
    #else
        url = ** Your Release URL **
    #endif
```

**Note : You add the DEBUG symbol with the -D DEBUG entry.**

Comment: I see I can use this preprocessor macro value in the code, so would it be a good solution to use the same named macro with different values for DEBUG and RELEASE? Something like DEBUG: API_URL = 1234, RELEASE: API_URL = 456. And then in the code I would just use url=API_URL...???

Comment: @ThomasKilian, Thank for your comment.. Just updated my answer.. please remove your down vote if you think it's proper now..

Comment: Thank You for the update Nilesh. I just tried it in the simulator and on the physical device and I always fell in the IF branch. Now I hope it will work in the released application too. I will also test it on the TestFlight because I am really excited if I will receive the DebugURL or ReleaseURL value...Edit: If I understand it depends on archive setup in scheme settings, or?