# Referring to Environment Variables in Swift

Tags: swift, environment-variables

Does anybody know how I can grab an environment variable in Swift?

Comment: Great article with helpful answers - https://medium.com/@danielgalasko/change-your-api-endpoint-environment-using-xcode-configurations-in-swift-c1ad2722200e

Answer (score 132):

**Swift 3 and up:**

```
import Foundation

if let value = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["KEY"] {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Careful. These env vars won't show up when you archive or launch the app away from Xcode.

Comment: @joshuakcockrell I learned it the hard way. Your comment saved me from another sleepless night. Thank you.

Comment: Use this if you want your env vars to persist even after archiving/shipping to TestFlight and/or App Store: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74254208/4975772

Answer (score 39):

Along with the `NSProcessInfo`-based method mentioned by Oleg, you can access environment variables using the the standard C `getenv` function, like so:

**Swift 2.x:**

```
func getEnvironmentVar(name: String) -> String? {
    let rawValue = getenv(name)
    guard rawValue != nil else { return nil }
    return String(UTF8String: rawValue)
}
```

**Swift 3.0:**

```
func getEnvironmentVar(_ name: String) -> String? {
    guard let rawValue = getenv(name) else { return nil }
    return String(utf8String: rawValue)
}
```

It's also possible to *set* environment variables using the `setenv` function:

```
func setEnvironmentVar(name: String, value: String, overwrite: Bool) {
    setenv(name, value, overwrite ? 1 : 0)
}
```

The reason I mention the ability to set variables is because it's the only way I know of to set variables when working in an Xcode Playground.

I recently wanted to see a backtrace for a strange `CGContext` error I was getting when working with a "live" view in a playground. By default, the backtrace isn't shown in the console, so I had to set the `CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE` environment variable to see what was up:

```
setenv("CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE", "1", 1)
```

After that, it was smooth sailing. Well, other than the `CGContext` error I was getting, but that's a topic for another day.

Hope this helps!

**P.S.** The above functions require the `Darwin` module to be imported. `Foundation` automatically imports `Darwin`, but I thought I should mention it nonetheless.

Comment: If you want to set environment variables for an Xcode project you can edit scheme > run > arguments section where you can add environment variables

Comment: thank you for the `setenv` tip. tried to make it work before with `Process()` and `ProcessInfo.processInfo` but couldn't never make the env stick. `setenv` fixes the issue for me.

Comment: didn't know about `setenv`--thanks!

Answer (score 16):

Yes it is possible. Use `ProcessInfo` for that.

Simple example :

```
let dic = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment
if dic["VAR"] != nil {

}
```

Comment: Ok, that work on running application, what do you do with the UI Tests?

Answer (score 13):

Since Swift 3 `NSProcessInfo` has been renamed to `ProcessInfo`.
And method `processInfo()` has been replaced with property `processInfo`.

```
import Foundation

for (key, value) in ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment {
    print("\(key): \(value)")
}
```

Comment: Here is Apple's official API doc for it: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/processinfo/1417911-environment

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use Info.plist file to store build-time env variables that your app needs at runtime, as described on [apple developers forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/700110):

> For example if you have a MyConfig.xcconfig file like this:
>
> ```
> MY_SECRET_API_KEY = mysupersecretapikeyvaluehere
> ```
>
> In your Info.plist you should add an entry like this:
>
> ```xml
> <key>MySecretApiKey</key>
> <string>$(MY_SECRET_API_KEY)</string>
> ```
>
> Finally in your code read the value of your variable like this:
>
> ```swift
> guard let infoDictionary: [String: Any] = Bundle.main.infoDictionary else { return }
> guard let mySecretApiKey: String = infoDictionary["MySecretApiKey"] as? String else { return }
> print("Here's your api key value -> \(mySecretApiKey)")
> ```

Answer (score 0):

A [Vapor](https://vapor.codes/) specific solution:

From the code which Vapor automatically A Vgenerates as a project template:

```swift
let variable = Environment.get("VARIABLE") ?? "or-the-dafault"
```

Comment: That API is specific to Vapor.

Comment: This is correct, but doesn't answer the OP's question.