# Swift environment variable returns nil when building app

Tags: swift, environment-variables, tvos

**Description**

I have a problem with environment variables. When I build my app and it's running, everything goes fine, but when I press "stop" or I archive it for app store, the environment variable returns nil (or an empty string, I'm not quite sure yet).

**How to reproduce:**

1. Build the app
2. Run it on the simulator ("Hello world" will appear)
3. Stop the app
4. In the simulator, go back in the app ("Hello word" won't appear)

**Minimal reproduction:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        label.text = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["testVariable"]
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

The label Outlet references a simple storyboard

[storyboard screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AOfd.png)

And here is the config for my env variables

[Variables configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGWFW.png)

Finally, here is a minimal reproduction of the problem on a github repo
https://github.com/MasterBroki/test-environment-variable

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Xcode passes environment variables from a scheme to the iOS runtime. When you run the application outside of Xcode, they are not passed. I've also run into this limitation, and you can find a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14214923/9165148).

An alternative to this approach is to use pairings of configurations (such as Debug, Release, or one you make for a specific purpose) and "Preprocessor Flags" OR "Other Swift Flags." You can find some guidance for this approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38813906/swift-how-to-use-preprocessor-flags-like-if-debug-to-implement-api-keys?answertab=votes#tab-top).

Answer (score 0):

Running into the same problem. Using normal Debug and Release config options with checks like

```
#if DEBUG
  <logic>
#else
  <logic>
#endif
```

works for me